# How can I write a bash function that puts all arguments into quotes?

Tags: bash, git

I want to alias git commit. Here’s what I have so far:
`function commit() { git commit -m "$@"; }`

This works for single word commit messages but breaks when you try `commit a message` for example. How do I retain spaces in quotes for the call made by my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
function commit() { git commit -m "$*"; }
```

See more here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Answer (score -1):

You can, of course, wrap it in quotes to be able to pass a multi-word message as an argument:

```
commit "this is my message"
```

Another option would be to use the `read` command that listens for input after the function has been called initially:

```
function commit() {
printf "Enter your commit message.\n";
read msg;
git commit -m "$msg"; }
```

You would just call `commit` and then enter your message at the prompt.